# How to test class with @Autowired using Spock

Tags: grails, testing, spock

I have a class in `src/groovy` like this

```
public class MyClass {

@AutoWired
SomeOtherClass someOtherClass

String test() {
    return someOtherClass.testMethod()
}
}
```

When I write a test for this method I am getting an error: `Cannot invoke method testMethod() on null object`.

This is my test :-

```
def "test test" () {
    expect:
        myClass.test() == "somevalue"
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to mock the `@Autowired` class?

Comment: did you try doWithSpring closure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mock your `someOtherClass`. Something like this

```
def "test test"(){
    setup:
    myClass.someOtherClass = Mock(SomeOtherClass)
    myClass.someOtherClass.testMethod() >> "somevalue"

    expect:
    myClass.test() == "somevalue"
}
```

Comment: this only works if this line is present `myClass.someOtherClass.testMethod() >> "somevalue"` instead of doing that I actually want the return value from the actual method instead of mocking the value for the method.

Comment: Then it's NOT a Unit Test. You should test `someOtherClass.testMethod()` in its own Spec, `SomeOtherClassSpec`. Calls into other classes should be Stubbed/Mocked.

Answer (score 1):

Though the previous answer should work, spock provide more elegant way of injecting beans as per need. You could use doWithSpring closure to declare beans just like spring dsl support provided in grails using `resources.groovy`.

```
class MyClass extends Specification{
def setup(){

   static doWithSpring={
       someOtherClass(SomeOtherClass)
       //declare below if want to inject myClass somewhere else as a bean else not
       /*myClass(MyClass){bean->
          someOtherClass = someOtherClass
      }*/
   }
}

def "test test" () {
    expect:
        myClass.test() == "somevalue"
}
}
```